# How to reference a model in Ember.js?

Tags: ember.js

I am working through toDoMVC and in the code below, just don't quite understand what `this` refers in `var model = this.get('model');`.

Does it refer to `Controller` or `Route`.  If it is `Controller`, then where do we declare that `Model x works with Controller y`?

```
Todos.TodoController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  isCompleted: function(key, value){
    var model = this.get('model');
    ...
  }.property('model.isCompleted')
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I.** Usually `this` variable inside `Ember.Object` functions refers to an instance of that `Ember.Object` (an instance of `Todos.TodoController` in your case).

Example:

```
App.SomeRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    activate: function() {
        this; // this is App.SomeRoute instance ref.
    }
});

App.SomeController = Em.Controller.extend({
    someMethod: function() {
        this; // this is App.SomeController instance ref.
    }
});

App.SomeView = Em.View.extend({
    someMethod: function() {
        this; // this is App.SomeView instance ref.
    }
});
```

and so on.

**II.** `this.get('model')` is just a property of controller (you can set any value to that property if you want). *Before ember v1.7 `model` was an `Ember.computed.alias` to controller's property named `content`, but this behavior [was changed](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.7.0/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/controller_content_model_alias_deprecation.js) in latest ember's versions.

There is another `model` property, in `Em.Route`, it differs from `Em.ObjectController.model` property. Actually, it's a function invoked in routing (transition) sequence, which returns data, which `Em.Route` uses to set a `controller.model` property in [setupController](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController) hook of `Em.Route`. So, output of `this.get('model')` inside of `Em.Route`'s methods will be a function.

P.S. I tried not to screw up with tenses, but most likely I didn't succeed.:) I'am sorry.